# fast 3D histogram python

Tags: python, performance, image-processing, histogram

I am looking for a fast way to itereate over pixels and create a 3D histogram and return an array sorted by the most used colors.

My actual code is :

```
def hist_3dhist(im):
    hist = {}
    for h in range(im.shape[0]):
        for w in range(im.shape[1]):
            if im.shape[2] == 4 and im[h, w, 3] == 0: ## if transparent pixel, no need to count it
                continue
            key = tuple(im[h,w,:3])
            if not key in hist:
                hist[key] = 0
            hist[key] += 1

    return sorted(hist, key=hist.get, reverse=True)
```

So to explain quickly : I create a dictionary with all the different colors, and the values are the number of times a color appear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Selecting the histogram bins with the largest counts can be disappointing because colors actually appear as gradients rather than perfectly constant areas, because of lighting effects. For this reason, the colors can be spread over many bins, and the bins be poorly populated. A dominant color can be superseded by a secondary one that has a smaller spread. To cope with this, use larger bins.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this function is for very specific images which are not real-world images but for patterns which do not contain a lot of colors.

Comment: Don't use a dictionary, use an array. It will be orders or magnitude faster. You need to pick a sampling for the array, because you don't want to create a 256x256x256 array. It's too large, too slow, and will have too many empty bins. Good sizes can be 32x32x32 or 64x64x64 bins, but it depends on the application. If you need an exhaustive list of all colors used, your method might be applicable, or you could sort the pixels and then keep the unique values. Which is faster depends on how many colors you have.

Comment: What is the range of the histogram (ie the min/max values in `im[h,w,:3]`)? Are the pixel colors integers in the range `[0;255]` ?